# validation spring service layer

Tags: java, spring, jsp, validation, service

I have a form  that I validate with implementing Spring Validator interface.
the validation concern just the fields in my form. I don't have problem with this, but what I want to do and I don't know how to proceed is to call in my controller a service method, and if this method return a specific value, return to the form page and display the error message in the jsp page.

Validator:

```
public class TrunkValidator implements Validator{

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
    return Trunk.class.equals(clazz);
}

public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {
    Trunk trunk = (Trunk) obj;

    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "compagnyName", "field.required", "Nom emtreprise est obligatoire");

    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "pbxName", "field.required", "Nom Pbx est obligatoire");


    if ( ! errors.hasFieldErrors("compagnyName")) {
        if ("trunk".equals(trunk.getCompagnyName()))
            errors.rejectValue("compagnyName", "sssss", "déja existant");
    }       
    }
}
```

Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createTrunk", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    protected ModelAndView createTrunk(@Valid Trunk trunk,
            BindingResult bindingResult) {
                // form validation
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("/jsp/createTrunk.jsp");
            model.addObject(ATTRIBUTE_BASE_URL, baseUrl);
            return model;
        } else {

                   //  if service method retun error message or exception
                   // display form with error message 

        }
    }
```

JSP:

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="trunk" action="${baseUrl}/createTrunk">
    <form:errors path="*" cssClass="errorblock" element="div" />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Nom de l'entreprise :</td>
            <td><form:input path="compagnyName" /></td>
            <td><form:errors path="compagnyName" cssClass="error" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Nom de PBX :</td>
            <td><form:input path="pbxName" /></td>
            <td><form:errors path="pbxName" cssClass="error" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>N° de commande :</td>
            <td><form:input path="orderNum" /></td>
            <td><form:errors path="orderNum" cssClass="error" /></td>
        </tr>



        <tr>
            <td>LDI :</td>
            <td><form:input path="ldi" /></td>
            <td><form:errors path="ldi" cssClass="error" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>INSEE :</td>
            <td><form:input path="insee" /></td>
            <td><form:errors path="insee" cssClass="error" /></td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `@InitBinder` in your controller:

```
@InitBinder("trunk")
public void initBinderAll(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(new TrunkValidator());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use annotations and @Autowired feature of spring:

Setup your servlet.xml like this...

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="sk.eglu.khl" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/mytheme/" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

...and then you can use annotations - so create interface of "TrunkValidator" and add to your service layer annotation like this:

```
public interface TrunkValidatorInt {

    boolean validate(Object obj, Errors errors);

}

@Service
public class TrunkValidatorImpl implements TrunkValidatorInt {

    @Override
    boolean validate(Object obj, Errors errors){
         return true;
    }

}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public class HelloWorldController{

        @Autowired(required = true)
        TrunkValidatorInt trunkValidator;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView helloWorld(){

    final ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("HelloWorldPage");

            if(trunkValidator.validate(someValue)){
        model.addObject("msg", "good!");
            } else {
        model.addObject("msg", "bad!");
            }
    return model;
    }
}
```

Also you can have a look on this starting project for Java where you can see how layers communicate:

https://github.com/majusko/GeneralJavaRest